# I don't understand what is wrong with this "if" statement

Tags: ruby

I have a simple program and I don't understand what is the problem.

```
(1..100).each do|i|
  if(i%3 == 0)
    puts "Fizz"
  elsif(i%5 == 0)
    puts "Buzz"
  elsif((i%5 == 0) && (i%3 == 0))
    puts "FizzBuzz"
  else
    puts "#{i}"
  end
end
```

Everything is working except for the numbers that are divisible by both 5 and 3.

When I run the program I get

```
1,2,Fizz,4,Buzz,.......,14,Fizz,...
```

What is the problem?

Comment: This is one reason fizz buzz still catches people out-debugging is at least as important as coding. Some simple print statements would tell you precisely what is happening, when.

Comment: Use `puts i` instead of `puts "#{i}"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every number that is divisible with 5 and 3, note that they make the condition `if (i%3 == 0)` true first. So the `elsif((i%5 == 0) && (i%3 == 0))` is never entered.

A simple fix is to check `((i%5 == 0) && (i%3 == 0))` first.

Comment: I tried that 5 mins ago but it did not work .. When I tried it now it worked . Maybe I modified something xD . Thank you .

Comment: You could cut it down to one evaluation by checking `i % 15 == 0`.

Answer (score 1):

If it is divisible by both 3 and 5, an earlier `if`/`elsif` would catch it.  That line should not be an `elsif`, it should be an `if`, or you need to test it before the individual parts.

Basically, the logic flow is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

You misunderstand that once the condition in `if` is met, it doesn't bother to check the rest of the conditions.

One clever way is to use mod 15 in this case like:

```
(1..100).each do|i|
  if(i%15 == 0)
     puts "FizzBuzz"
  elsif(i%3 == 0)
    puts "Fizz"
  elsif(i%5 == 0)
    puts "Buzz"
  else
    puts "#{i}"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a slightly more straightforward way to do it, without the need to check for all cases.

Create an array and place your resulting string there.

- If the number is divisible by 3, append Fizz to the array.
- If the number is divisible by 5, append Buzz to the array.

  - Note in doing this, if we have a number divisible by 3 *and* 5, we append Fizz and Buzz to the array.
- If we haven't pushed anything at all to the array, append the numeral instead.
- Join all elements of the array and print that instead.

Here's a snippet.

```
def fizzbuzz
  (1..100).each do|i|
    r = []
    if(i % 3 == 0)
      r << "Fizz"
    end
    if(i % 5 == 0)
      r << "Buzz"
    end
    if r.empty?
      r << i
    end
    puts r.join
  end
end
```